# unusual SQL Exception in java, using derby database

Tags: java, sql, derby

Below is the code which i am using for getting the values form the database:

```
try {

  Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();
  connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/TedW;user=x;password=x;");
  PreparedStatement statement = connect
      .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM USER");

  resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    String user = resultSet.getString("Username");
    String password = resultSet.getString("Password");
    System.out.println("User: " + user);
    System.out.println("ID: " + password);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

the problem is that when i run it it shows the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 15.
```

I see that there is some problem with the table name "USER". I saw it when i created the database its the same. It is amde in Derby. Below is the code for that:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER"
(
"Id" INT not null primary key generated always as identity (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
"Username" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
"Password" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

);
```

Where could i probably be wrong? Am i missing something? Can i get some insights into it?

Thanks.

Comment: You posted your username and password.  Probably not a good idea.

Comment: Oh! thanks, I'll see to it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`USER` is a reserved keyword and you cannot name your table like that. Check [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html).

Comment: If you really want to use the word USER as the name of a table or column, etc., you can put it in double quotes, as in SELECT * FROM "USER"

Comment: Indeed -- you can. However, in my opinion, that would be very poor practice as it is likely to cause you grief later on with the fact that you will need to take care of escaping SQL code.